# UITextView URL interaction handle

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

I have a `UITextView` with `selectable = true`, i`sUserInteractionEnabled = true`, `dataDetectorTypes = .all`

and i use `UITextViewDelegate`:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
for recognizer in textView.gestureRecognizers! {
  if recognizer.isKind(of: UITapGestureRecognizer.self) {
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
      return true
    }
  }
}
  longTouchCell()
  return false
}
```

If a single tap is done to the URL, then I want to open this URL by returning true, else I would like to do custom action `longTouchCell()`.

However, sometimes a single tap also triggers custom action `longTouchCell()`. Namely, if after a custom action, I wait for some time duration long enough and do a single tap again, then it works as expected, but a quick tap right after a long press will trigger as if the case of a long press.

Comment: Make `longTouchCell()` call in background.

Comment: Can you explain why? My main problem is that the single tap to trigger openning link is no always true, thus leading to longTouchCell, which is expected to be executed on long press